# How to redirect ostream to Boost Log library

Tags: c++, boost

I have a progress bar function that takes a std::ostream as a parameter. I have simplified it here for description purposes.

```
void someprogressbar(std::ostream & stream)
{
    stream << "Hello";
}
```

I can't modify this function, as it is a third-party function. I call this function with either `std::ostringstream myoss; someprogressbar(myoss)` or with `someprogressbar(std::cout)`. The function prints some info in real time as my program progresses.

How can I redirect the output to the Boost Log library? I can do `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "Hello"`, but can't do `someprogressbar(BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug)))`.

Comment: write a neat little streambuf (of a Boost Iostream Sink) and implement it to write to boost log. (This will likely already be implemented by someone)

Comment: I'm still struggling with understanding sinks. I setup a global Boost logger that prints to the console and multiple files. Is is here that I need to hook this streambuf? Could you point me to a tutorial or an example? I have not been able to find an example that implements what I need.

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to solve this. I will post an answer later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to redirect output to the Boost logger through an ostream, I needed to create a sink using the Boost Iostreams library. Thanks @sehe for the hint!

I use C++11 in the following implementation:

```
#include <iosfwd>
#include <boost/iostreams/categories.hpp>

class Logger_Sink
{
public:

    typedef char char_type;
    typedef boost::iostreams::sink_tag category;

    Logger_Sink() = default;

    virtual
    ~Logger_Sink() = default;

    virtual
    std::streamsize
    write(
            char_type const * s,
            std::streamsize   n) = 0;
};

class cout_Sink: public Logger_Sink
{
public:

    std::streamsize
    write(
            char_type const * s,
            std::streamsize   n)
    {
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << std::string(s, n);
        return n;
    }
};
```

Then, I needed to use this sink to create an ostream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
namespace io = boost::iostreams;

io::stream_buffer<cout_Sink> cout_buf((cout_Sink()));

std::ostream mycout(&cout_buf);
```